# how do iterate a Vector Autoregression(VAR) function based on the number of states/regimes?

Tags: r

I have created a Markov switching Vector Autoregression function in R limited to 2 states/regimes. My challenge is how you iterate the function that serves more than 2 states/regimes.

This is the function below only limited to 2 states/regimes.

```
  # Output 
     for (i in 2:length(states)){
        y[, i] = case_when(
          states[[i]] == 1 ~ constant[,1] + theta %*% (y[, (i-1)] - mean) + et[,i],
          states[[i]] == 2 ~ constant[,2] + theta %*% (y[, (i-1)] - mean) + et[,i]
        )
      }
```

where y[, i] is the current value depending on the previous value y[, (i-1)], constant[,1] and constant[,2] are constants for states 1 and 2 respectively and et[, i] are errors that are IID.

How do you iterate the function to serve 2 or more states/regimes?

Comment: What is `states` here?

Comment: Markov chain states/regimes